# Reference request: Using randomized interpolation to apply KS-Test to discrete distributions

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I'm dealing with $n$ samples $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ from $n$ different (but related) distributions with CDFs $F_n$.

If all the distributions were continuous, I could use the transformation $U_i := F_i(X_i)$, which yields $n$ independent samples uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, and then use a KS-Test to check wether the samples indeed come from the distributions I think they do.

But my distributions are *not* continuous - the domain of my $X_i$ is a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$. There are, of course, discrete versions of the KS-Test, but they all seem to test $n$ samples taken from one distribution, not $n$ samples taken from $n$ distributions. The best solution I could come up with so far is to randomly interpolate when computing $U$. I set $$
  U_i = F_i(X_i-1) + Q_i*\bigl(F_i(X) - F_i(X_i-1)\bigr)
$$
where $Q_1,\ldots,Q_n$ are indepent and uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$.

So far this seems to work - it my simulations, the KS-Test produces uniformly distributed p-Values when apply to the randomly interpolated $U_i$, and if the $X_i$ are indeed samples from the correct distributions.

However, I haven't been able to find any literature on this kind of random interpolation, and the effect it has on KS-Tests. In particular, I wonder if it would make sense to separately test the $Q_i$, and if their p-Value is low, correct the p-Value obtained from the $U_i$.

Any kind of pointer to relevant literature, or any idea how to approach this from a different angle would be much appreciated.